# Pyspark on windows throws exception while running job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I Run this simple code:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Apache Log Analyzer")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
logFile = 'access.log'
parsed_logs = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()
print(parsed_logs.first())
```

But it Throws an Exception and I Can not Understand why.
Exception :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (DESKTOP-NJ1U5NV.mshome.net executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=183, Cannot create a file when that file already exists
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=183, Cannot create a file when that file already exists
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:453)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 15 more
```

Image of Exception:

[image]

I'm Just Trying to Print the First Element of DataFrame.
How Can I Fix this?

Comment: yes I did and I searched a lot for it. what is this file exactly?